# Google Script that can translate thousands of rows of technical language to another language

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]**Problemdescription**
There are thousands of rows (all in one column, C1) that are names of different products in english. Each cell contains an arbitrary amount of words (definition of word is that the string can be split where there is a " ", then each substring is a word). For each cell there is one part of it that is technical jargon and the rest are words that can be translated using google translate.

There are four other columns, two columns in the original language and two of the desiered language (swedish). C2 represents each technical jargon and the resulting translation in swedish is stored in C3 so that "Cut-off wheel" in Cell `C2_{i}` then the translation in swedish "Kapskiva" is found at `C3_{i}`. Column C4 are always single words and the resulting translation in swedish is found in the same row but in C5.

I need to create a script in Google Script, that can simply translate each productname from english to swedish using the supporting columns C2-C5.

**My Code (so far)**

```
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultingTranslation = [];

  for (i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var fullProductName = values[i][1];
    var nameToList = fullProductName.split(" ");
    var resultingList = [];

    for (j=0; j < values.length; j++) {
      var nameENJargon = values[j][2];

      for (h=0; h < nameToList.length; h++) {
        if(nameToList[h] == nameENJargon) {
          resultingList[h] = values[j][3];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    for (k=0; k < values.length; k++) {
      var nameENTranslate = values[k][4];

      for (n=0; n < nameToList.length; n++) {
        if(nameToList[n] == nameENTranslate) {
          resultingList[n] = values[k][5];
          break;
        }
      }
    resultingTranslation[i] = resultingList;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(resultingTranslation);
}
```

**My comments**
For each entry in C1, I take the string and split it into a List of substring, where each entry in that list is a word. Then I simply iterate over the columns C2 and C4 to look if any of these substrings have a match. The problem is that since some words in the technical jargon column C2 contain multiple words, I need to find a way that it can take multiple substrings from my nameToList, so that if "Cut-off" is not in C2, then perhaps "Cut-off wheel" does. And if it does, I need to find a way to iterate it so that it then doesn't start to look for "wheel" in C2. And I also need it to not be case-sensitive...

**Expected results from script**

Before translation: "SiC Grinding Paper Ø230mm P60"

After translation: "SiC Slippapper Ø230mm P60"

Before translation: "Diamond cut-off wheel A Ø75 x 0,3/5 x 12,7mm"

After translation: "Diamantkapskiva Typ A Ø75 x 0,3/5 x 12,7mm"

As you can see here, "Grinding Paper" and "Diamond Cut-off wheel", both two words gets translated into one word in Swedish, and I'm not sure how to solve it properly for my code...

SiC, Ø230mm, P60, A, Ø75, x, 0,3/5, x and 12,7mm are all words found in C4 and are easy to translate. But Diamond cut-off wheel and Grinding Paper are in C2 and are harder (I find..)

Comment: If you want someone to do it for you I would suggest you give them an image of your sheet.  Some may follow a link to your spreadsheet.  Personally, I would not but then it doesn't matter because I'm not interested in doing it for you.

Comment: I think a better approach here would be to iterate over each column separately; do you also have a screenshot of how _exactly_ does the spreadsheet look like as well? @Alexander

Comment: Ok, I thought adding them together would make more sense...I've pasted a picture of the sheet now! @ale13

So Column B is the thing to translate, Column C has all the technical jargon in english, D the swedish technical jargon, E has the random english words and F has the swedish translation of said word.

All columns but B are much bigger than the picture can show. Column B only contains a fraction of all the products, since I'm trying the code a lot...

Comment: Have you considered making use of the `LanguageApp`? Also, do you require these words to be translated in this specific manner? For example - `"Diamond cut-off wheel ` will be translated as `Diamantskärhjul`, which seems to be different from what you are expecting but I assume they have the same meaning @AlexanderSöderhäll